# Split the list of values based on target value

Tags: java

I am trying to find possible combinations for the given target (double value) in the list of objects   , I have tried below way and got results but not sure whether this is efficient or not .Is it possible to achieve the same result without recursive approach by using java 8 packages or any third party API?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Test {
    private double amt;
    private int id;
    private String fund1;
    private String fund2;

    public double getAmt() {
        return amt;
    }

    public void setAmt(double amt) {
        this.amt = amt;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Test(double amt, int id) {
        super();
        this.amt = amt;
        this.id = id;
    }

    static void getPossibleComb_recursive(ArrayList<Double> numbers, double target, ArrayList<Double> partial) {
        double s = 0;
        for (double x: partial) s += x;
        
        if (s == target)
            System.out.println("sum(" + Arrays.toString(partial.toArray()) + ")=" + target);
            
        if (s >= target)
            return;
            
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Double> remaining = new ArrayList<Double>();
            double n = numbers.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); j++) remaining.add(numbers.get(j));
            ArrayList<Double> partial_rec = new ArrayList<Double>(partial);
            partial_rec.add(n);
            getPossibleComb_recursive(remaining, target, partial_rec);
        }
    }

    static void getPossibleComb(ArrayList<Double> numbers, double target) {
        getPossibleComb_recursive(numbers, target, new ArrayList<Double> ());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List <Test> a = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Test> b = new ArrayList<>();
        Test a1 = new Test(2345.65, 1);
        Test a2 = new Test(2000, 2);
        //Test a3 = new Test(120,3);
        //Test a4 = new Test(140,4);
        
        a.add(a1);
        a.add(a2);
        //a.add(a3);
        //a.add(a4);

        Test b7 = new Test(10, 7);
        Test b8 = new Test(10, 8);
        Test b9 = new Test(10, 5);
        Test b10 = new Test(10, 6);
        Test b11 = new Test(10, 7);
        Test b12 = new Test(10, 8);
        Test b13 = new Test(10, 5);
        Test b14 = new Test(10, 6);
        Test b15 = new Test(10, 7);
        Test b16 = new Test(10, 8);
        Test b17 = new Test(10, 8);
        Test b18 = new Test(10, 5);
        Test b19 = new Test(20, 6);
        Test b20 = new Test(20, 7);
        Test b21 = new Test(100, 8);
        Test b1 = new Test(586.41, 5);
        Test b2 = new Test(586.41, 6);
        Test b3 = new Test(586.41, 7);
        Test b4 = new Test(586.42, 8);
        Test b5 = new Test(1000, 9);
        Test b6 = new Test(1000, 10);

        b.add(b1);
        b.add(b2);
        b.add(b3);
        b.add(b4);
        b.add(b5);
        b.add(b6);
        b.add(b7);
        b.add(b8);
        b.add(b9);
        b.add(b10);
        b.add(b11);
        b.add(b12);
        b.add(b13);
        b.add(b14);
        b.add(b15);
        b.add(b16);
        b.add(b17);
        b.add(b18);
        b.add(b19);
        b.add(b20);
        b.add(b21);

        Double[] numbers = b.stream()
            .map(am -> am.getAmt())
            .toArray(Double[]::new);

        for (Test test: a) {
            getPossibleComb(new ArrayList <Double> (Arrays.asList(numbers)), test.getAmt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid starting with a lower-case letter for a class name. Likewise, non-final variables should not be upper-case. These two things make if difficult to skim your code efficiently. Please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: If this is working code you should probably post it in [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  instead. [this might be useful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow)

Comment: Performance issue with the  code taking very long time to get combinations